# "React must be in scope when using JSX" (react/react-in-jsx-scope with "window.React = React" on index.js)

Tags: reactjs, jsx, create-react-app, react-dom

I am following Chapter 5, "React with JSX", of "Learning React" from O'Reilly.

I wrote the Recipes App using `create-react-app` as the base.

**index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import './index.css';

import App from './App';
import Menu from './Menu';

import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import data from './data/recipes';

window.React = React;

ReactDOM.render(<Menu recipes={data} />, document.getElementById('root'));

registerServiceWorker();
```

**Menu.js**

```js
import Recipes from './Recipes';

const Menu = ({recipes}) => (
    <article>
        <header>
            <h1>Delicious Recipes</h1>
        </header>
        <div className = "recipes">
        {recipes.map((recipe, i)=>    
            <Recipes key={i} {...recipe}  />
        )}
        </div>
    </article>
);

export default Menu;
```

And  have the following error:

```sh
Failed to compile ./src/Menu.js
  Line 5:   'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
  Line 6:   'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
  Line 7:   'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
  Line 9:   'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
  Line 11:  'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
    
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

The book says "setting `window.React` to `React` exposes the React library globally in the browser. This way all calls to `React.createElement` are assured to work". But it seems like I still need to import React on each file that uses JSX.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Import React on top of your Menu.js file:

```
import React from 'react'
```

React should always be imported in a particular file, that uses JSX if you are working with this library (React) in your project.

Comment: This Doesnt hold true for React 17 +

Comment: But I do see this error with react 18.0.0

Comment: I also have this error when running Docker in a container, React 18.0.0

Comment: I use react18.2.0 and I still get this error. I thought it was because I was using eslint and I added the rule {"react/jsx-uses-react": "off", "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",} but it still did not work @ShanmukhaSampathKumar

Answer (score 7):

In react 17 there is no need to import.
We can write code without importing react from React

https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html

> Together with the React 17 release, we’ve wanted to make a few
> improvements to the JSX transform, but we didn’t want to break
> existing setups. This is why we worked with Babel to offer a new,
> rewritten version of the JSX transform for people who would like to
> upgrade.
>
> Upgrading to the new transform is completely optional, but it has a
> few benefits:
>
> - With the new transform, you can use JSX without importing React.

eslint default config for react will still warn about it. But that can be disabled:

https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/react-in-jsx-scope.md

> If you are using the new JSX transform from React 17, you should
> disable this rule by extending react/jsx-runtime in your eslint config
> (add "plugin:react/jsx-runtime" to "extends").

Comment: This was useful, because the error started when I downgraded from v17 to v16.13.1.

Comment: create-react-app does not warn about that anymore. it is probably fixed. but eslint default config does. So might be better to disable that rule: react/react-in-jsx-scope

Comment: These links show what to do to the well-informed, but changing eslint config is not something that beginners will be familiar with. Would it be possible to add step-by-step instructions? The linked docs may be canonical, but they're not very transparent!

Answer (score 4):

This happens due to “React” import necessary in JSX file. The React library must also always be in scope from JSX code because JSX compiles as a react.

in your case 'React' must be import in Menu.js,

```
import React from "react";
```

[this is an error most beginner react developers made.](http://sandny.com/2019/10/24/the-most-common-errors-and-warnings-that-beginner-react-developers-make/#more-404)

[And also You can refer](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#react-must-be-in-scope)

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE 2022**

Importing `React` is considered as "unused import" and is recommended to be removed on longer term, see [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#removing-unused-react-imports).

I got this error when setting up linter, here this is also pointed out by the [eslint documentation](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/react-in-jsx-scope.md#when-not-to-use-it), that you don't the need extra import from the React version 17 on.

Answer (score 2):

This is as aresult of not importing React module from 'react' properties hence you can try importing the module and try using 'export' when declaring a function so that it will be easy to import them in other pages using 'import {Menu} from menu' as shown below

```
import React from 'react';
import Recipes from './Recipes';

export const Menu = ({recipes}) => (
    <article>
        <header>
            <h1>Delicious Recipes</h1>
        </header>
        <div className = "recipes">
        {recipes.map((recipe, i)=>    
            <Recipes key={i} {...recipe}  />
        )}
        </div>
    </article>
);
```

Comment: add some context to explain how your answer will solve problem, that will really help the community in long run