# Error : 'React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope. (tried import react but not working)

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO2o2.png)

please check the jpg & help me out if you need the code then comment down below

Comment: You should add code as text not image

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["React must be in scope when using JSX" (react/react-in-jsx-scope with "window.React = React" on index.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49335781/react-must-be-in-scope-when-using-jsx-react-react-in-jsx-scope-with-window-r)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640636/react-must-be-in-scope-when-using-jsx-react-react-in-jsx-scope)

Answer (score 0):

In older react versions `import React from 'react` had to present in the file when jsx was used.

Either add
`import React from 'react`
to the beginning of the file or update react version to 17 or 18